# Как заставить цикл do while работать правильно?

Tags: php, циклы

Для получения информации по последним сделкам из amoCRM используется метод [GET leads/list](https://developers.amocrm.ru/rest_api/leads_list.php). Использую цикл do while. Если количество элементов в массиве, который мы получаем, меньше или больше 500, то цикл работает нормально и заканчивает работу, когда получен массив с последними сделками (от 1 до 499). Если же элементов в массиве 500, то цикл работает бесконечно, и не останавливается, хотя должен остановиться, так как в последнем полученном массиве количество элементов равно 0 ($count_leads). Как заставить цикл работать правильно?

```
$limit_offset = 0;

do
{

$link='https://'.$subdomain.'.amocrm.ru/private/api/v2/json/leads/list?limit_rows=500&limit_offset='.$limit_offset;
$curl=curl_init(); #Сохраняем дескриптор сеанса cURL
#Устанавливаем необходимые опции для сеанса cURL
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'amoCRM-API-client/1.0');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); #PHP>5.3.6 dirname(__FILE__) -> __DIR__
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); #PHP>5.3.6 dirname(__FILE__) -> __DIR__
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$out=curl_exec($curl); #Инициируем запрос к API и сохраняем ответ в переменную
$code=curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
CheckCurlResponse($code);
if($out)
{
$Response=json_decode($out,true);
$leads_list = $Response['response']['leads'];
}

$count_leads = count($leads_list);
$limit_offset = $limit_offset+500;

}
while ($count_leads == 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень силен в PHP. Я так думаю, что в последней итерации не выполняется условие if($out) и $leads_list'у не присваивается значение (остается предыдущее, т.е. количество 500) и не выходит из цикла.

Comment: Можно попробовать до проверки условия if($out) обнулить $leads_list = [], или же обнулить в условии в блоке else

Answer (score 1):

Чудес не бывает. Если в условии написано `$count_leads == 500` и цикл при этом работает бесконечно - значит, в переменной `$count_leads` и правда раз за разом оказывается 500.

Я понимаю, отладка `php` по шагам - дело не модное, но может, все-таки [попробуете](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/HowToSetupDevelopmentEnvironmentWindows)?